# What would be a good split character for splitting concatenated base64 strings?

Tags: string, split, base64

I have a number of base64 strings that I need to concatenate to send over HTTP.

Is there a good character to use to split the strings (I'm guessing a character that is invalid inside a base64 string).

-thanks for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since base64 only contains characters, digits and + and /, anything else should do - how about a space, a comma (',') or a pipe symbol ('|') ?

Comment: well, it could also contain '=' as padding character. But yes, I'd recommend any whitespace or comma, that way it'd be easier to visually read as well as parse.

Comment: Note that it's "common" to display base64 by putting a \n every 76 characters (at least on Linux). So if you want to use whitespace, you probably want to go for \n\n or something.

Comment: I think pipe symbol would be the best option.